# ffmpegのsegmentオプションについて質問です。

Tags: ffmpeg

ffmpegを使用してセグメントファイルを作ろうとしているんですが、試しにテスト用ファイルでやるとsegmentのつくオプションが使えないとでます。例えばsegment_timeとかのオプションです。
ffmpeg -hでffmpegのオプションが見れますが、そこにはsegmentはありませんでした。
segmentのオプションが使えるffmpegの場合はそこにsegmentがでるんでしょうか？

もしなかった場合ffmpegをコンパイルし直す必要があるんでしょうか？

Comment: `ffmpeg -formats 2>/dev/null | grep segment` を実行してみて、`E segment         segment` などの文字列が表示されるのであれば使用できるはずです。

Comment: それと、`ffmpeg -h full` とすれば、(segment 関連の機能が使えるのであれば) `segment_time` などが表示されることになります。

Comment: ありがとうございます！おかげでsegmentが使えることが確認できました！

Answer (score 1):

`ffmpeg -formats 2>/dev/null | grep segment` を実行してみて、`E segment segment` などの文字列が表示されるのであれば使用できるはずです。

それと、`ffmpeg -h full` とすれば、(segment 関連の機能が使えるのであれば) `segment_time` などが表示されることになります。